# can anyone help me out why I am getting null value even there is no error in the code

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, android-progressbar

```
package com.example.myquizapp
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.TextView
```

here is my code

```
class QuizActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var progressBar : ProgressBar?= null
    private var tvProgress : TextView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
            progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
```

on hover R.id.progressBar I get :public static final int progressBar = 1000004

```
            tvProgress = findViewById(R.id.tv_progress)
```

// public static final int tv_progress = 100000

//on hover progressBar I get : private final var progressBar: ProgressBar?

```
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz)

            var currentPosition = 1
            progressBar?.progress=currentPosition                       
            tvProgress?.text="${currentPosition}/${progressBar?.max}"
            Log.e("currentPosition" "${currentPosition})        // 1
            Log.e("ProgressBar", "${progressBar}")    // null, getting null value on logcat
            Log.e("TvOrogress", "${tvProgress}")// null, getting null value on logcat
            Log.e("tvProgress",${tvProgress?.text.toString}  // null

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `findViewById()` calls after `setContentView()`.

`setContentView()` inflates the view hierarchy and adds it to the activity. `findViewById()` looks up view in the activity view hierarchy, and it is empty before `setContentView()` so `findViewById()` returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Move findViewById() to onViewCreated method

```
  override fun onViewCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
            progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
```